# Instagram Basic Info without AccessToken

Tags: android, api, instagram

Can I get Instagram Full Name and Profile picture without Access Token. It seems I can't find any API for that.

I tried with:

```
https://www.instagram.com/{username}/media
```

But, I get only media if user has pictures and if user is public.

I found some android apps get Full Name and profile picture only with Username, I need something like that in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do similar kind of thing last month but Actually there are no official APIs for that ,
there is this website https://openinstagram.com idk how those guys crated this APIs but you can try this:

https://api.openinstagram.com/{username}

and replace the text username with any real username and you will get profile picture and full name of that user even if the user is private, 
this is not the only example, there are multiple website running on same kinda thing website like web.stagram and websta and it's mentioned on there website that they aren't certified by Instagram (because they are using unofficial APIs)
hope this would help.